Can I query a knowledge base and generate a response WITH streaming using Bedrock?
I am successfully using RetrieveAndGenerate from bedrock, but is there an equivalent that would allow streaming?
I would like to use websockets to render the characters one at a time to the user for a more pleasant experience.

no you dont have direct support for that  you will need custome streaming solution

What do you mean by custom streaming solution?

get the response > chunk it > create a websocket to send those chunks to client > render the chunks as they arrive imitating streaming

Ha right, but then it would be smoke and mirrors as this could be done on the client side. We were hoping to save on latency as well.

everything comes with advantage and disadvantage you are on the latter side for this one for now but hope support for this comes up soon as per your requirement.

No you cannot by using this API. However, you can use the retrieve API and ask an LLM to generate the response using the content retrieved. You would need to format your prompt with the chunk you retrieved. But this gives you more flexibility like enabling streaming but also using a model which might not even be in Bedrock.
